# Long starting with zero has wrong value

Tags: java, string, methods

I'm trying calculate the number of numbers in the long variable. However, if i declare
`long number = 0123456` -> 5.
But when I declare
`long number = 123456` -> 6.
Sorry my English isn't good. Thank you. This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  long number = 0123456;
  System.out.println(getSize(number));
}

public static int getSize(long d){
        String number = Long.toString(d);
        return number.length();
    }
```

Can anyone explain for me please, thank you.

Comment: `0123456` is octal. It's equivalent to the decimal `42798`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1

Comment: try `System.out.println(Long.toOctalString(number));`